# How to setup CSRF in JavaScript for laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, csrf, csrf-protection

I only use JavaScript.

And i know jQuery will set's the CSRF by,

```
  $(function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
       'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

But how could i use "CSRF-Token" in JavaScript ?

Is there any possibilities for common setup for all Ajax Call ?

Comment: What do you mean by how could I use?

Comment: ajaxSetup sets headers with csrf token for every ajax request

Comment: You do understand that jQuery *is* Javascript, right? Are you asking how to add a CSRF token to an AJAX request's headers without using jQuery?

Comment: Exactly...I'm not using jquert for Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

To use csrf token common for all the ajax calls you have put following code in your master layout blade file.

In layout header:

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

In your layout footer:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">   
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {       
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({        
            headers: {            
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')        
            }    
        });    
    });
</script>
```

This will work for all your ajax requests.

Thanks

Comment: I only want for JavaScript, not for jQuery !

Comment: In javascript you have to set token oin headers for each request. Like xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);

Answer (score 3):

You can include layout header look same above

But if you want use pure javascript to include token you can use:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url , true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content );
xhttp.send(params);
```

Hope to help your code ^^

Answer (score 1):

**You can pass csrf token in ajax as like this:**

```
   $.ajax({  
             url: "/user.php",  
             method:"post",  
             data: { 'user_id':user_id,
                    '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}" }, 
             success:function(data){console.log(data);}
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem as you. But I have found the solution and you can take a look at this article [How to include csrf_token() in an external js file in Laravel?](https://www.bookc.tech/2022/11/how-to-include-csrf-token-in-an-external-js-file-in-laravel).
You just add a meta tag to your html

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And hopefully can help your problem.