# Laravel 5.4.30 : How to get csrfToken？

Tags: laravel

How to get `csrfToken` in Laravel `5.4.30` ?

In older version, There is a piece of code like this:

```
   <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
```

So, I could get `csrfToken`  in javascript like this:

```
Laravel.csrfToken
```

Now I update laravel to `5.4.30`,the code above has been moved,and in `bootstarp.js`,there is a piece of code like this:

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
```

**Quesion：**
How to get `csrfToken`  in javascript now ?

Comment: you can use Laravel Helper function `csrf_token()`

Answer (score 3):

You should tr this:

**1.** add  tag with the token to the blade layout:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**2.** setup ajax requests:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
 or
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: I will use it in javascript,not php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383026/how-to-setup-csrf-in-javascript-for-laravel

please follow this url . i think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

if you need it for ajax calls, you can try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

and in the head of you blade:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! Session::token() !!}">
```